# Determining polynomials such that their Galois group is of small order

Tags: galois-theory

This might be a weird question. If we are given a polynomial $f$ of degree $\leq 6$ over a field $K$, then it is possible (hard?) to compute the order of the Galois group.

Conversely, is it possible to find a polynomial, ie to determine the coefficients of a polynomial (for degree up to 6) with the condition that we want its Galois group, ie the order of the splitting field to be small ? Ideally we would have the polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. What conditions should we satisfy ? Or is this even possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: For the second question, what counts as small?

Comment: @EthanAlwaise I don't have a specific way to quantify "small". My question is pretty vague... but I am trying to see if there are any particularities to a polynomial that influences on the size of its Galois group basically.

Comment: Without any other information, the only thing you can say is that the order of the Galois group is $\leq \deg(f)!$. If the polynomial is irreducible, then the group must act transitively on the roots, which will put further restrictions on the *kind* of group it can be - and hence on its size.